# split to remove multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with the split function to get the output as below-

'name' has a value
cDOT_abc_esx_01_test_wi13_03-31-2020_22.20.01.8964

Code-

```
(j['name'].split("_wi13_"))
```

I am getting output as below-

```
'cDOT_abc_esx_01_test', '03-31-2020_22.20.01.8964'
```

I only want output as below-

```
'cDOT_abc_esx_01_test', '03-31-2020'
```

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning regular expressions (regex) will be and advantage in these kind of situations. Just an opinion..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(string_1.split("_wi13_")[0], string_1.split("_wi13_")[1][0:10])
```

Comment: better add another split with _ separator

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve it in the single split operation?
In my script i only want it with a single split operation

Comment: Is there any other context that could help us answer your question? I feel like you're looking for something more specific...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import re
reg=re.compile("^(.*?)_wi13_([^_]+)")
rtn_val=reg.findall(s)[0]
```

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve it in the single split operation? In my script i only want it with a single split operation

Comment: Fixed.I used regex,I think it's more helpful than Kasinath PS :)

Comment: Or,if you want a one-liner,use:`rtn_val=re.findall("^(.*?)_wi13_([^_]+)",s)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can first split the string using `'_wi13_'` as you did, and then use the second element of the list and split it further on `"_"`

```
name = 'cDOT_abc_esx_01_test_wi13_03-31-2020_22.20.01.8964'

fs = name.split("_wi13_")

fs[1] = fs[1].split("_")[0]

print(fs)

# output
['cDOT_abc_esx_01_test', '03-31-2020']
```

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve it in the single split operation? In my script i only want it with a single split operation

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
first, second = j['name'].split("_wi13_")
output = (first, second.split("_")[0])
```